# How to merge two Maps in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to merge 2 Maps. In ES6 I would do it like so and it works perfectly fine:

```
const m1 = new Map();
m1.set('foo', 1);

const m2 = new Map();
m2.set('bar', 3);

const m3 = new Map([...m1, ...m2]);
```

If i do the same in TS i get the following an error:

```
Type 'Map<string, number>' is not an array type.
```

I assume that i have to cast it to array somehow but I did not find a working solution. How should i go about fixing this issue?

Comment: The spread operator only works for `Map`s,`Set`s in ES6 mode. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856#issuecomment-222879485

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works also with target ES5:

```
let map1:Map<string, number> = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);
let map2:Map<string, number> = new Map([["c", 1], ["d", 2]]);

let mergedMap:Map<string, number> = new Map([...Array.from(map1.entries()), ...Array.from(map2.entries())]);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a short syntax:

```
const map1 = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])
const map2 = new Map([["c", 1], ["d", 2]])

const mergedMaps = new Map([...map1.entries(), ...map2.entries()])
```

Answer (score 7):

If you target es5 for the Typescript compilation, you get this error. If you can you should target es2015 for the Typescript compilation and then the error will not appear (in tsconfig.json for example):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015"
    }
}
```

The spread operator only works for Maps,Sets in ES6 mode. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856#issuecomment-222879485 That's because it ignores the spread operator and it is output as is. Another way to say it, TypeScript doesn't transpile spreads for Map/Set.